# Android 5.1 : Attempt to write to field 'java.util.ArrayList android.animation.AnimatorSet$Node.nodeDependents' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to write to field 'java.util.ArrayList android.animation.AnimatorSet$Node.nodeDependents' on a null object reference

I got this issue after move from Android 5.0 to 5.1, it happens when I am trying to inflate with cloned LayoutInflater. It will be OK if I just use the regular layout inflater. Also this inflation is happening on background thread with threadPool executor because two same layouts were needed to inflate at same time for performance reason. It would also be OK if I switch to use serialized executor.

```
final LayoutInflater bgLayoutInflater = layoutInflater.cloneInContext(getContext());
final ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) bgLayoutInflater.inflate(resourceId, null, false);
```

[link to the AOSP where crash happens, line 699](http://androidxref.com/5.1.0_r1/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/animation/AnimatorSet.java)

Any ideas?

Comment: This feels like a dumb suggestion, so I'm saying it in a comment rather than an answer. Have you tried doing a Clean Build of your project? In Android Studio you click Build > Clean Project. Maybe it's just some weird reference problem if you didn't actually change any of your code when you changed APIs.

Comment: No suggestion is dumb, though it does not solve my problem.@Chamatake-san

Answer (score 1):

So finally I figured out this problem on my own. Regardless the new 5.1 AOSP change should return a nicer error to tell me what went wrong, I was inflating a big layout in background thread on my own risk.

Here is I believe what happened.

```
final LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)
            getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
```

I need to inflate two big layout (600ms each) with the fastest time, so I decided to have asyncTask with threadPoolExecutor to execute the two inflation tasks. But I can't achieve it because the layoutInflater from SystemService is **synchronized**. So I made a cloned inflater that solved the problem until 5.1.

Now I am able to fix it with

```
 final LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
```

So that each inflater is doing its own job in parallel. Again I am still at my own risk of inflating not on UI thread, in the future a new update may still break it somewhere.